# Package clash between enotez and gmverse while using several paragraphs in an endnote

Tags: packages, endnotes, verse, enotez, gmverse

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enotez}
\usepackage{gmverse}

\begin{document}

\begin{verse}
foo\endnote{bar

baz}
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

When I use a linebreak in an `\endnote` command I get at the compilation the following error message:

```
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/gmverse/gmverse.sty) (./main.aux)
Runaway argument?
{bar
! File ended while scanning use of \enotez@note.
<inserted text>
                \par
l.5 \begin{document}

?
```

The problem does not appear when I don’t use line break or when I use an `\endnote` with multiple paragraphs outside the `verse` environment.

So how can I use linebreak inside an endnote inside a `verse` environment?

---

## 1st Edit

The MWE asked in comments

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enotez}
\usepackage{gmverse}

\begin{document}

\begin{verse}
The main verse\endnote{
  The endnote content

  \begin{verse}
    A second verse\\
    Contained in the first one\\
  \end{verse}
}
\end{verse}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\endnote{bar\\baz}` works (if you remove your previous `.aux` file first), but doesn't have indents.

Comment: Well, it’s not a real solution because inside the `\endnote` I whant to place another `verse` environment. But then, the `\\` command doesn’t work inside it.

Comment: It might help if you expanded your MWE to show what you want to do (e.g., regarding verse in the edndnote).

Comment: `gmverse` does `\catcode` juggling, so it is essentially impossible to have it in the argument to another command.

Comment: I’ll close this question because I discover a more specific cause of this problem in the following question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/603988/gmverse-package-break-verse-in-endnote