# gmverse package break verse in endnote

Tags: packages, endnotes, verse, enotez, gmverse

### Situation

When `gmverse` package is called in the preamble and I put a `verse` environment inside and `\endnote` command provided by `enotez` package, so the verse didn’t interpret the `\\` command for line break.

### This is my MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{gmverse}
\usepackage{enotez}

\begin{document}


Shakespear wrote the following poem to the queen\endnote{\begin{verse}
As the dial hand tells o'er\\
The same hours it had before,\\
Still beginning in the ending,\\
Circular account still lending,\\
So, most mighty Queen we pray,\\
Like the dial day by day
\end{verse}
}

\printendnotes

\end{document}
```

### This is the rendering

[image: Rendering result]

### Expected result

But normaly, when `gmverse` package isn’t called in the preamble, I should get a result like this one:
[image: Expected result]

### Question

Who can I get normal verse rendering inside `\endnote` when `gmverse` package  is called in the preamble?

Comment: You seem to have discovered problems with the `gmverse` package. What does it provide so that you want to use it?

Comment: Yes you get it @PeterWilson :D So, it provide only one feature I need, but I can’t for the moment get it without `gmverse`: The french hanging of long verses like the red parts here https://i.imgur.com/YP57yPr.png .

Answer (score 1):

Going back, I think that you only use `gmverse` because it automatically provides "French Hanging". I have tried, but failed to entice the `verse` package to do this but found that there is a way to do this manually using the `\\>` linebreak command.

```
% newverseprob.tex  try for French hanging

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{verse}

\newcommand*{\fh}{\mbox{} \hfill [ }
%%%% I couldn't automate it
\makeatletter
\renewenvironment{verse}[1][\linewidth]{%
  \stepcounter{verse@envctr}%
  \setcounter{poemline}{0}\refstepcounter{poemline}%
  \setcounter{vslineno}{1}%
  \let\\=\@vscentercr
  \list{}{\itemsep \z@
          \itemindent  -\vindent%
          \listparindent\itemindent
          \parsep       \stanzaskip
          \ifdim #1 < \linewidth
            \rightmargin        \z@
            \setlength{\leftmargin}{\linewidth}%
            \addtolength{\leftmargin}{-#1}%
            \addtolength{\leftmargin}{-0.5\leftmargin}%
          \else
            \rightmargin        \leftmargin
          \fi
          \addtolength{\leftmargin}{\vindent}}%
%      \fh
  \item[] 
%     \fh 
}
{%\fh
 \endlist}
\makeatother
%%%%%% but it can be done maually

\begin{document}

\poemtitle{In the Beginning}
\settowidth{\versewidth}{And objects at rest tended to remain at rest}
\begin{verse}%[\versewidth]
Then God created Newton, \\
And objects at rest tended to remain at rest, \\
And objects in motion tended to remain in \\> \fh
motion, \\
And energy was conserved
  and momentum \\> \fh was conserved
  and matter \\> \fh was conserved \\
And God saw that it was conservative. \\
\end{verse}


\end{document}
```

[image]

I have no idea if the out.put is what you are after. If not, maybe someone else might be willing/able to help you